# System.Diagnostics.Process program keeps on running

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, process.start

I'm trying to convert some avi files into mkv using ffmpeg library from a commandline application.  I made a method that allows me to do that:

```
public bool convertAvitoMkv(string path, string sourceName, string destName)
    {

        bool returncode = false;
        try
        {
            string comando = string.Format("-i {0} -c:v libx264 -crf 19 -preset slow -c:a libfaac -b:a 192k -ac 2 {1}", string.Format("{0}\\{1}",path,sourceName), string.Format("{0}\\{1}",path,destName) + ".mkv");
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = programPath;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.Arguments = comando;
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();
            while (!process.HasExited)
            {
                process.Kill(); 
                //continue hasta que termine la ejecucion
            }

            returncode = process.HasExited;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return returncode;
    }
```

the previous version did not have the while (!process.HasExited), but I added it because I noticed that there were a lot of instances of ffmpeg.exe running that I had to close by hand.  How can I guarantee that every conversión is made and that every instance of ffmpeg is closed?
regards

Comment: Does ffmpeg hang when you try to convert the same files manually (by running it directly from the command line)?

Comment: You're killing the process right after starting it - starting a process is a long, time-consuming process and `HasExited` is almost guaranteed to be `false` right after calling `Start`. You should use `Process.WaitForExit` instead. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: originally the lines while (!process.HasExited)
            {
                process.Kill();                 
            }
were not there.  I added them after seeing a lot of ffmpeg processes on task manager in an effort to avoid that but it didn´t work

Comment: Did you verify that ffmpeg quits normally on the files you're trying to convert? And `WaitForExit` has a timeout parameter.

Comment: when working directly on command line, ffmpeg does not take longer tan 1 sec.  Ffmpeg shows a list of processes made.

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the same exact parameters to ffmpeg from your code than from the command-line? Specifically, are the file paths exactly the same, accounting for the fact that the current directory is set for your process.

Comment: using the combination right after process.start: process.WaitForExit();
                    //process.Close();
                    process.Dispose();  using close, or dispose makes the trick. One thing to consider too is to check that files did not exists already

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool concatenarArchivos(string archivos, string path, string destName)
    {
        bool returncode = false;
        try
        {
            string[] extensions = {".mp4"};
            string[] dirContents = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*").Where(f => extensions.Contains(new FileInfo(f).Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();
            if (dirContents.Length > 0)
            {
                string comando = string.Format("-f concat -i {0} -c copy {1}", archivos, string.Format("{0}\\{1}", path, destName));
                System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                startInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
                startInfo.WorkingDirectory = programPath;
                startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                startInfo.Arguments = comando;
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();
                //process.Close();
                process.Dispose();
                //returncode = process.HasExited;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return returncode;
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't access any properties of `Process` after you call `Dispose`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. When debugging I noticed that when I used `WaitForExit`, it kept waiting indefinitely. When I used the while loop with `!process.HasExited`, it also did not get passed the while loop.

As soon as I added both a redirect for the standard output and error, and read the streams it started working like expected.

It seems that when there is some kind of output (regular and/or error) the process keeps waiting until the output has been processed. Before it will not exit.

Changing your code as follows will most likely solve your problem.

```cs
public bool convertAvitoMkv(string path, string sourceName, string destName)
    {

        bool returncode = false;
        try
        {
            string comando = string.Format("-i {0} -c:v libx264 -crf 19 -preset slow -c:a libfaac -b:a 192k -ac 2 {1}", string.Format("{0}\\{1}",path,sourceName), string.Format("{0}\\{1}",path,destName) + ".mkv");
            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = programPath;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.Arguments = comando;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();

            StreamReader readerOut = process.StandardOutput;
            StreamReader readerErr = process.StandardError;
            // Process the readers e.g. like follows
            string errors = readerErr.ReadToEnd();
            string output = readerOut.ReadToEnd();

            while (!process.HasExited)
            {
                continue; 
            }

            returncode = process.HasExited;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return returncode;
    }
```

Comment: nice comment...recently I found that for some unknow reason, certain processes kept on running.  i'll try that.. thanks